# verbatim с переносом строки

Tags: latex

Мне необходимо в своем отчете вставить кусок кода чистым текстом, но с обычным verbatim-ом он постоянно выходит за пределы полей и документа, опция [breaklines=true] не работает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте пакет `listings` - там можно гибко настроить и переносы, и выделение ключевых слов и много что еще.